# ESXi 6.7 with Two NICs in Different Subnet

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have HPE ProLiant DL380 8G with four NICs. Installed ESXi6.7, and statically configured first NIC for management access in private subnet,172.139.248.0/24 and I have been able remotely access the server via web browser. I have connected the second NIC to a NAT'ed router, that should assign me an IP in 192.168.1.0/24 subnet, so that future created VMs can reach the Internet but I'm unable to get any IP address. I have created VMs using EVE-NG & CentOS images but both VMs were unable to get any IPs other than loopback address. So, how can I fix this issue of keeping two separate subnets? I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normaly, this is no problem. Is the second NIC assigned to the right vSwitch? Please tell us more about your vSwitch configuration.

Comment: Yes, I have created new Port Group and second vSwitch (inet & vSwitch1 respectively) and associated two physical adapters to them (vmnic1 & vmnic2) and both of them are up.
The only time I was able to get and IP address for vmnic1 is when I removed the configuration for the first subnet from the equation. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to use public IP addresses that belong to AOL for that subnet?